# Difference between custom type and primitive type

Tags: go

I have a quick doubt about Go types.

```
type mystr string
var s1 mystr = "abc"
var s2 string = "abc"
```

Here s1 always takes string type which is similar to s2. My question is, why defining such *types* are allowed (which are of primitive types) in Go. When I can't even compare s1 to s2

```
if s1 == s2 // compilation error
```

What can be the use case to such scenario?

Comment: Named types can have methods, built-in in types cannot: https://tour.golang.org/methods/3

Comment: " I can't even compare s1 to s2." You can compare `s1` and `s2`. For example https://play.golang.org/p/tDjoLy7Yggm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is similar to extension methods in other programming languages. You can add your own behavior to your type (and cannot in standard type):

```
type MyStr string

func (s MyStr) Length() int {
    return len(string(s))
}

func main() {
    s := MyStr("hello")
    fmt.Println(s.Length())
}
```